# Formatting Excel Table for Percent of total by specific column

Tags: database, excel

I have a table in excel that I'm databasing information in. In this particular excel it is demographic data of students in a certain course across the state of Texas. You can see below that it is filtered by Ethnicity/Hispanic Latino.

[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrQxI.png)

It's clear to see that the percent row is utter-non sense. What I would really like this last column to do is tell me of what percent all those who took the survey are Hispanic. This becomes tricky because I would like to filter it for all of our "sub-data" as well. So whether I filter it for age, grade, most common language spoken, etc. I'd like to see the percent of that sub data there.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUBTOTAL():

```
=[@Number]/SUBTOTAL(109,[Number])
```

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to make that work. I can put @number for the total of each specific sub category, such as hispanic/latino, white etc. But I'm not sure how to reference [number] in the subtotal formula to get the total of all students who took the test.